# How to correctly use a callback function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, callback, request

Alright. Trying to make a *very* simple request here. First code with asynchronous Nodejs. According to everywhere I've checked, I'm doing this right. None of them explained really *how* callbacks work, they just say what to do, so I have no way of figuring it out intuitively.

```
const request = require("request");

function fetchData(url, json, callback) {
    request({
        url: url,
        json: json,
        method: "get"
    }, callback(error, response, body))
}

console.log(fetchData("https://www.yahoo.com", false, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        return body;
    } else {
        return error;
    }
}));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things- first, pass the callback variable into `request()`, don't call the function.

`callback` vs `callback()`

Second, you can't use the return value from the callback function. Call `console.log()` from inside the callback function.

**Code with changes:**

```
const request = require("request");

function fetchData(url, json, callback) {
    request({
        url: url,
        json: json,
        method: "get"
    }, callback)
}

fetchData("http://www.yahoo.com", false, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. Will verify to see if it works soon. The ultimate goal was to return the html from the site. You are saying that console.log will achieve this in the callback?

Comment: @JoelMorris What happens is that you are able to use the results of the request within the callback function. This means you can pass it to functions that do output such as `console.log`, or whatever else you need within the callback. The callback is called by the `request()` function, so anything you return from the callback just gets discarded since the request function doesn't know how to handle it. Generally, if a callback function can return a value, the documentation will tell you what the callback can or should return.